# How to combine two Fields in SelectList edit ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my case in SelectList show me Just UsersFirstName I need to add near of UsersFirstName UsersLastname
Asp.net MVC

```
 ViewBag.StoreAccountManager = new SelectList(db.USERS, "UsersId", "UsersFirstName", STORE.StoreAccountManager);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create a new type

```
class MyUsers
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    };
```

then use it like this

```
  var query = from u in db.Users
            select new MyUsers
            {
                id = u.UsersId,
                name = u.UsersFirstName+ " " + u.UsersFirstName

            };
            List<MyUsers> list = query.ToList();
 ViewBag.StoreAccountManager = new SelectList(db.USERS, "id", "name", STORE.StoreAccountManager);
```